# Pull Email from list data and forward

Tags: list, email, flow

When a item is created or modified I receive an alert in my inbox. This is the OOTB alert, which is really nice because it provides great detail and identities changes of an item.

What I want to happen now is that alert be forwarded to the “assigned to” email address from the item. Like this...

Email received as SP alert > data pulled from the list / item (I imagine this will be done external of the actual email but via the list / item itself) > email forwarded to the “assigned to” email address

Seems pretty straight forward when I write it out but I can’t seem to find a way to pull the data needed from the list and apply that to an email already received then forward accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

If your list is an Issue Tracking or Tasks list, then you can enable the E-Mail Notification setting in List Settings > Advanced settings. This setting emails the user when ownership is assigned or when an item has been changed.

If you're not using this type of list, you could create a SharePoint workflow that emails the "Assigned To" user when an item has changed. You can do this by setting the workflow to run when an item has changed.